# Angular - parent class constructor with arguments and `super` call

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, constructor

So I have this child class instantiating a service that is not used in the parent :

```
export class ChildService extends ParentService {
  constructor(protected someService: SomeService) {
    super();
  }
}
```

And the parent instantiating another service not used by the child :

```
export class ParentService {
  constructor(protected otherService: OtherService) {

  }
}
```

So obviously this won't work, I need to send the argument in the `super` call. The thing is, I really don't like the idea of instantiating a service in a child just so I can send it over to the parent. That's the solution I found everywhere.

I found another way also, that would be to use `ServiceLocator.injector` in the parent in order to avoid having the service as a constructor argument :

```
export class ParentService {
  protected otherService: OtherService;

  constructor() {
    this.otherService = ServiceLocator.injector.get(OtherService);
  }
}
```

But it honestly feels a bit messy as well. I'm looking for a clean solution for this.

My specific use case is a `data.service` using `HttpClient` and being inherited by class-specific services. All `HTTP` calls would then be handled in the `data.service`. Maybe there is a better way to achieve this abstraction!

Comment: You shouldn't **instanciate** someService. You should **inject** it, just as you inject otherService.

Comment: Well I do exactly the same for both, I don't get what you mean

Comment: I inverted the parent and the child: `constructor(protected someService: SomeService, otherService: OtherService) {
  super(otherService);
}`. That **injects** the two dependencies of the child service into its constructor.

Comment: Yes but that's exactly what I want to avoid. `httpClient` service is only used in `data.service`, and following that path would mean I need to instanciate it in each and every child of `data.service` just to inject it for the parent ! That looks so clumsy.

Comment: Not instanciate. Inject. Insanciate means "create a new instance". It isn't clumsy at all. It's perfectly normal: A child**is a** parent. That's what inheritance is about. So The parent dependencies are the child dependencies, and must thus be injected. But maybe you should use delegation rather than inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I don't really like it visually but logically you're right.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this ?

Comment: I got over it and rolled with @JBNizet explanation.